# Drawing vertical arrow to a table column

Tags: tables, arrows

I would like to draw an arrow to the center of a table column as the following. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to place the arrow in a `\multicolumn` to remove any of the `tabular` vertical rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\downarrow$} \\ \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ \hline
  %...
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you both. How I didn't think of multicolumn I don't know. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the obligatory `tikz` solution which then gives you all the flexibility inherent in `tikz` in terms of adjusting the arrow tips, colors, line styles, etc.

### Note:

- As with all `\tikzmark` solutions, this does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

---

### Automated Solution:

In the earlier *manual* solution below, each column for which the arrow was to be drawn needed to be marked with an individual `\tikzmark`.  This makes the table a bit harder to read.

In this solution, I have used the [the `collcell`  package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) to define a new column type `C` to replace the `c` columns (as well as `R`, `L` columns). When this column type is used the column is automatically marked with a `\tikzmark` numbered `1,...,<numberof columns>`.  So, the table just need to look like:

```
\begin{tabular}{|CCCCCCLR|}\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & wide text & 6 & 7 & 008 \\ \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & wide text & 8 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

After the table to you can use the `\DrawArrow` macro to draw the arrow to *any* of the columns in the table by using the column number as the paramater to `\DrawArrow`. For example the `\DrawArrow[-stealth]{3}` produces the third black arrow:

[image]

### Notes:

- This automated solution assumes that you will draw at least *one* arrow whenever the `C`, `R`, or `L` column types are used.  Without this the counter which numbers the columns would not be reset. Otherwise you could just manually call `\ResetAddTikzMark` before the start of each table, and this would be a non-issue.
- Only the special columns types are numbered, so if you use `CrC`, then the first `C` column would be numbered `1`, and the third column would be numbered `2` (since it is the 2nd column that gets the automatic `\tikzmark`.

### Further Enhancements:

- Note that column `7` is using the `L` column type.  Since the first column's text is used to compute the width (to center the arrow), the arrow points to the center of the first column's text, which may not be the desired outcome.  If this is not clear, see column `8` which is using the `R` column type.

  One way (untested) to adjust his would be to ensure that that columns text was wrapped in a `\makebox[\widthof{<widest-text-in-column>}]{}` type of macro.

---

### Manual Solution:

In this version each of the top rows where you want to add the arrows needs to be marked with a `\tikzmark`:

[image]

### References:

- Solution is adapted from [Draw a line through one column of a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47730/draw-a-line-through-one-column-of-a-matrix/47739#47739)

---

### Code: Automated Solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newlength{\TextWidth}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
    \settowidth{\TextWidth}{#2}%
    \makebox[\TextWidth]{%
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] 
            \node [anchor=base] (#1) {#2};
    }%
}

\newcommand{\DrawArrow}[2][]{%
  \ResetAddTikzMark% Reset counter for next table
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[-latex, thick,#1] ($(#2.north)+(0,1.0cm)$) -- (#2.north);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcounter{ColumnCounter}
\newcommand*{\ResetAddTikzMark}{\setcounter{ColumnCounter}{0}}
\newcommand*{\AddTikzmark}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{ColumnCounter}%
    \tikzmark{\arabic{ColumnCounter}}{#1}%
}%

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\AddTikzmark}c<{\endcollectcell}}%
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\AddTikzmark}r<{\endcollectcell}}%
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\AddTikzmark}l<{\endcollectcell}}%

\begin{document}
\vspace{2.0cm}
\begin{tabular}{|CCCCCCLR|}\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & wide text & 6 & 7 & 008 \\ \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & wide text & 8 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%
% Now we can draw the arrows to each of the `C` columns
\DrawArrow{1}
\DrawArrow[->]{2}
\DrawArrow[-stealth]{3}
\DrawArrow[red]{4}
\DrawArrow[blue, densely dotted]{5}
\DrawArrow[brown, thin, densely dashed]{6}
\DrawArrow[violet, ultra thick, dashed]{7}
\DrawArrow[magenta, thick, -stealth]{8}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Manual Solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {$#2$};}

\newcommand{\DrawArrow}[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[-latex, thick,#1] ($(#2.north)+(0,1.0cm)$) -- (#2.north);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}\hline
  \tikzmark{A}{1} & \tikzmark{B}{2} & \tikzmark{C}{3} & \tikzmark{D}{4} & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\DrawArrow{A}
\DrawArrow[->]{B}
\DrawArrow[red]{C}
\DrawArrow[blue, dotted]{D}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|c}|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\downarrow$} \\
\hline
A & B & C & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...no need for [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) here...