# how to draw a vertical arrow with text over it?

Tags: arrows

I need to draw a vertical arrow along the rows of a matrix with a text to its left side. Can anyone please help ? I tried to use multicolumn environment but that does not work.

Comment: Please add the code you tried as a minimal working example from which we can start to help you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Please add a picture of what you are trying to do, along with what you have attempted. In the mean time have a look at: [Draw a line through one column of a matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47730/draw-a-line-through-one-column-of-a-matrix),  [Draw a vertical line over the entries of a column in an array](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196258/draw-a-vertical-line-over-the-entries-of-a-column-in-an-array) and [Drawing vertical arrow to a table column](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75480).