# Draw a vertical line over the entries of a column in an array

Tags: arrays

I'd like to draw vertical/horizontal lines over the entries of a column/row in an array. I find the method to draw horizontal lines at [Draw a horizonal line over the entries of a row in an array](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79741/draw-a-horizonal-line-over-the-entries-of-a-row-in-an-array).
But when I used the same way to draw the vertical lines. It didn't look well.
My codes are:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawLine}[3][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [#1] ($(#2)+(0,0.6ex)$) -- ($(#3)+(0,0.6ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{displaymath}
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
\tikzmark{11}{15} & 0 & \tikzmark{13}{0} &0\tikzmark{14} \\
0 & 50 & 20 & 25 \\
35 & 5 & 0 & 10\\
\tikzmark{41}{0} & 65 & \tikzmark{43}{50} & 65
\end{array}
\right].
\DrawLine[black,thick]{11}{14}
\DrawLine[black,thick]{11}{41}
\DrawLine[black,thick]{13}{43}
\end{displaymath}
```

The result looks like

[image]

But the result I want is

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an adaption of [Draw a line through one column of a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47730/draw-a-line-through-one-column-of-a-matrix):

[image]

### Notes:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- Another option is to use the `tikzmark` package, but for this particular case it is simpler to *not* use that package: The custom defined `\MyTikzmark` provides anchor points `.north` and `.south` which are automatically centered vertically. Similarly `.east` and `.west` are centered vertically. In the `tikzmark` package version the lines were extended via `shorten >=` and `shorten <=` and shifted using `yshift` to provide similar results.

### Code: Without `tikzmark` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyTikzmark}[2]{%
     \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {$#2$};%
}

\newcommand{\DrawVLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[shorten <=0.3ex, #1] (#2.north) -- (#3.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\DrawHLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[shorten <=0.2em, #1] (#2.west) -- (#3.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    \MyTikzmark{leftA}{15} &  0 &  \MyTikzmark{topB}{0} &  \MyTikzmark{rightA}{0} \\
     0 & 50 & 20 & 25 \\
    35 &  5 &  0 & 10 \\
    \MyTikzmark{bottomA}{0} & 65 & \MyTikzmark{bottomB}{50} & 65
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\DrawVLine[red, thick, opacity=0.5]{leftA}{bottomA}
\DrawVLine[orange, thick, opacity=0.5]{topB}{bottomB}
\DrawHLine[blue, thick, opacity=0.5]{leftA}{rightA}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: With `tikzmark` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}

\newcommand{\MyTikzmark}[2]{%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline] 
        \node [anchor=base, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] 
            {\tikzmark{#1 LEFT}$#2$\tikzmark{#1 RIGHT}};%
 }

\newcommand{\DrawVLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[shorten <=-1.7ex, shorten >=-0.3ex, #1] 
            ($(pic cs:#2 LEFT)!0.5!(pic cs:#2 RIGHT)$) -- 
            ($(pic cs:#3 LEFT)!0.5!(pic cs:#3 RIGHT)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\DrawHLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[shorten <=-0.2em, shorten >=-0.3em, yshift=0.7ex, #1] 
            (pic cs:#2 LEFT) --  (pic cs:#3 RIGHT);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    \MyTikzmark{leftA}{15} &  0 &  \MyTikzmark{topB}{0} &  \MyTikzmark{rightA}{0} \\
     0 & 50 & 20 & 25 \\
    35 &  5 &  0 & 10 \\
    \MyTikzmark{bottomA}{0} & 65 & \MyTikzmark{bottomB}{50} & 65
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\DrawVLine[red,   thick, opacity=0.5]{leftA}{bottomA}
\DrawVLine[orange,thick, opacity=0.5]{topB}{bottomB}
\DrawHLine[blue,  thick, opacity=0.5]{leftA}{rightA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you update the answer taking into account that now there is a library for `\tikzmark`?

Comment: @egreg: Added a `tikzmark` package version, but for this case I think it is easier to _not_ use the package. See "Notes" section.  Apologies for the delay in responding.

Answer (score 6):

No real need for TikZ here, although I would not pretend this solution is very robust.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\smash{\vrule width .5pt depth 42pt height 4pt}&&
\smash{\vrule width .5pt depth 42pt height 4pt}\\[-8pt]
\hbox to 0pt{\vrule width 1in depth -3pt height 3.5pt\hss}
15&0&0&0\\
0&50&20&25\\
35&5&0&10\\
0&65&50&65
\end{array}\right]$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would do this differently using a `matrix of math nodes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}]{
      15 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
      0 & 50 & 20 & 25 \\
      35 & 5 & 0 & 10\\
      0 & 65 & 50 & 65\\
     };
     \draw[thick,black](M-1-1.west)--(M-1-4.east);
     \draw[thick,black](M-1-1.north)--(M-4-1.south);
     \draw[thick,black](M-1-3.north)--(M-4-3.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The `(M)` argument to `\matrix` means that you can refer to the nodes as `(M-row-col)`.

Note that you need to escape the delimiters as `{[}` and `{]}`.
This gives:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Without `tikzmark` or `matrix of nodes` , a simple solution is to use the `\rule` command with proper adjustment of `lift`, `width`, and `length`. Here is how to implement this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{bmatrix}
  15\makebox(-10,0){\rule[-18.5ex]{0.4pt}{4\normalbaselineskip}} 
     & 0 & 0 \makebox(-5,0){\rule[-18.5ex]{0.4pt}{4\normalbaselineskip}} 
             \makebox(-25,0){\rule[1.5ex]{6\normalbaselineskip}{0.4pt}} 
               & 0 \\
  0  & 50 & 20 & 25 \\
  35 & 5  & 0  & 10 \\
  0  & 65 & 50 & 65
\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

The output as required:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd have a go at it too.  I tried to compute as much as possible, but still need fudge factors to vertically center the lines over the numbers.  At least it should be independent of font size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newlength{\tempwidth}
\newlength{\tempheight}

% drwa horizontal line across matrix
\newcommand{\hmline}{\rlap{\rule[.6ex]{\tempwidth}{.5ex}}}

% draw vertical line up from bottom row of matrix
\newcommand{\vmline}[1]% #1 = comun entry (bottom row)
{\begingroup%
\settowidth{\tempwidth}{$#1$}%
\addtolength{\tempwidth}{-.5ex}% line width
\rlap{\hspace{.5\tempwidth}\raisebox{-.8ex}[0pt][0pt]{\rule{.5ex}{\tempheight}}}#1%
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
% compute size of matrix (no brackets}
\savebox{\tempbox}{$\displaystyle\begin{matrix}
    15 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
     0 & 50 & 20 & 25 \\
    35 &  5 &  0 & 10 \\
     0 & 65 & 50 & 65
\end{matrix}$}%
\settoheight{\tempheight}{\usebox{\tempbox}}%
\settodepth{\tempwidth}{\usebox{\tempbox}}%
\addtolength{\tempheight}{\tempwidth}%
\settowidth{\tempwidth}{\usebox{\tempbox}}%

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    \hmline
    15 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
     0 & 50 & 20 & 25 \\
    35 &  5 &  0 & 10 \\
    \vmline{0} & 65 & \vmline{50} & 65
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: matrix]