# How do I put a side brace around several lines in the align* environment?

Tags: align

I would like to put a side brace around several lines in the `align*` environment, as shown in the comments in the code below:

```
\begin{align*}
    left side & = right side \\
    left side & = right side \\  %   }
    left side & = right side \\  %   }-  these three lines are important
    left side & = right side \\  %   }
    left side & = right side \\
\end{align*}
```

Comment: You can try the `cases` environment if the direction doesn't matter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need any additional packages to do this. Here's a way using a regular `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
    f(x) & = a \\
    g(x) & = ax + b \\
    h(x) & = ax^2 + bx + c \\
    i(x) & = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \\
    j(x) & = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\[
  \setlength{\jot}{4.5pt}
  \begin{array}{r@{\;}l}
    f(x) & = a \\[\jot]
    g(x) & = ax + b \\[\jot]
    h(x) & = ax^2 + bx + c \hspace*{3em}
      \smash{\left.\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\\[\jot]\\[\jot]\\[\jot]\end{array}\right\}} \\[\jot]
    i(x) & = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \\[\jot]
    j(x) & = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e
  \end{array}
\]
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

On the left is the regular `align*` environment (from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)), while the right should an `array`. A zero-height 3-row `array` with only a right `\}` delimiter is added to the middle equation to group the output.

---

Another option, this time using [`blkarray`](http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}% http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
    f(x) & = a \\
    g(x) & = ax + b \\
    h(x) & = ax^2 + bx + c \\
    i(x) & = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \\
    j(x) & = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\[
  \def\arraystretch{1.1}
  \begin{blockarray}{r@{\;}l}
    f(x) & = a \\[\jot]
    \begin{block}{r@{\;}l\}}
      g(x) & = ax + b \\[\jot]
      h(x) & = ax^2 + bx + c \\[\jot]
      i(x) & = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \\[\jot]
    \end{block}
    j(x) & = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e
  \end{blockarray}
\]
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

You may have to play around with the vertical displacement, compared to the `align*` environment.

Comment: +1. In fact I was trying to do without tikzmark. nice work.

Answer (score 11):

There should be other ways of doing this. But I like the `tikzmark` way. The references are

1. [By Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570) and
2. [search in this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Tikzmark)

Some part of the code is adopted with thanks from reference 1.

I have used different placements depending upon the length of your equations (you choose suitable one or find your own placement hopefully). Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % to show the frame
%
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
%
\begin{document}
\hfill\tikzmark{right}
\begin{align*}
    left side & = right side \\
    left side & = right side  \tikzmark{first}\\
    left side & = right side long and very long  long and very long long and very long  \\  
    left side & = right side  \tikzmark{second}\\ 
    left side & = right side
\end{align*}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate,ultra thick,red]
($(right)!(first.north)!($(right)-(0,1)$)$) --  ($(right)!(second.south)!($(right)-(0,1)$)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{align*}
    left side & = right side &\\
    left side & = right sideE and very long  long long  long long  long &  \tikzmark{third}\\
    left side & = right side & \\
    left side & = right sidee & \tikzmark{fourth}\\
    left side & = right side &
\end{align*}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.4em},decorate,ultra thick,gray]
(third.north east) --  (fourth.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{align*}
   && left side & = right side                      & \\
   && left side & = right sideE and very long  long long  long long  long &&  \tikzmark{fifth}\\
   && left side & = right side                      & \\
   && left side & = right sidee                     & \tikzmark{sixth}\\
   && left side & = right side                      &
\end{align*}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.7em},decorate,ultra thick,blue]
(fifth.north east) --  (sixth.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
% The simple and using \phantom{}
\begin{align*}
   left side & = right side   \\
   left side & = right side bigger equation  \tikzmark{seventh}\\
   left side & = right side   \\
   left side & = right side \phantom{bigger equation}  \tikzmark{eigthth}\\
   left side & = right side  
\end{align*}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate,ultra thick,magenta]
(seventh.north east) --  (eigthth.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

As suggested by Peter Grill, one can define a macro like

```
\newcommand{\EmBrace}[3][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
        \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate,ultra thick, #1] (#2) -- (#3);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
```

for marking anywhere in the document repeatedly like

```
\EmBrace[magenta]{seventh.north east}{eigthth.east}
```

If the color is not specified, `black` will be used by default.

**EDIT-2:**

Next try with an ugly hack of `ams cases` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%-----------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{rightcase}{%
  \matrix@check\cases\env@cases
}{%
  \endarray\right\}%
}%
\def\env@cases{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left.
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\,\,}l@{}}%
}%
\makeatother
%%-----------------------------------
\begin{document}
%%-----------------------------------
\begin{align*}
    f(x) & = x^{2} + x +10   \\
  g(x) & = \\[-17pt] % Little eyeballing should help to decide this value.
  f(x) + g(y)  & =  \begin{rightcase}
                    x^{2} + x +10 - y^{2} + y\\
                    x^{2} + x\\
                    y^{2} + 2y + 10
                   \end{rightcase} \\[-17pt]
     g'(y) & =  \\
    f(x,y) & = x^{2} + x +10 + y^{3}
\end{align*}
%%-----------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the entire bunch of equations need to be covered, then `empheq` package must be of interest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
%-----------------------------------
\begin{document}
%-----------------------------------
\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[right=\empheqrbrace]{align*}
a_1(x) &= b_1\\
a_2(x) &= b_2\\
a_3(x) &= b_3
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
%-----------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]