# How to align equations when some inside are gathered

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I have a set of equations where some are coupled with a brace and some text. I want all the equations aligned. Something like the following ASCII art:

```
 S = LR

 L = Ls                |  for s in {a, b}
Rs = sR  /
```

I tried this:

```
\begin{align*}
S &= LR \\
\left.
\begin{gather*}
L &= L_s\\
R_s &= sR
\end{gather*}
\;\;\right\}\;\;\text{for } s \in \{a, b\}\\
\end{align*}
```

But it doesn't compile (because `&` is not expected inside a `gather*` environment). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Replace `gather*` with `aligned`. Remark: NO `*`.

Comment: possible duplicate [how-do-i-put-a-side-brace-around-several-lines-in-the-align-environment/](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51847/how-do-i-put-a-side-brace-around-several-lines-in-the-align-environment/51852#51852)

Comment: @zeroth: if I do that, the equations outside the aligned don't align with the ones inside.

Comment: @cmhughes: thanks, I'll take a look at that

Comment: @Max, yes that is correct, sorry for my misguiding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple way would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
S &= LR \\
\begin{split}
L &= L_s\\
R_s &= sR
\end{split}\quad\Bigg\}\,\,\text{for } s \in \{a, b\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The only thing I'd change is to use `\bigg` instead of `\Bigg`. Of course, that's entirely subjective. :-)

Comment: In my actual document, there are more than two equations inside the brace, so \Bigg is not big enough. I guess I have to mess around with vphantoms and the like to get bigger?

Comment: @Max: you can then use stretchable delimiters and a rule with no width and desired height: `\begin{align*}
S &= LR \\begin{split}
L &= L_s\R_s &= sR\T_s &= sT
\end{split}
\quad\left.\rule{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}\right\rbrace\,\,\text{for } s \in \{a, b\}
\end{align*}` (sorry about the poor code formatting, but comments are not the best place to write code).

Comment: Is there any way where the size of the brace is automatically calculated?