# Background images for code listings

Tags: graphics, listings, backgrounds

I've been searching around but I can't find any info for adding an image background for my code listing using the `listings` package. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is (always? ;-)) a way via TikZ...

Comment: Follow up Question: [Background images for code listings in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64211/background-images-for-code-listings-in-beamer).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As PolGab says, there is always a `tikz` way. Here is one that uses the infamous `\tikzmark` to mark the begin and end of the listing, and then adds an image clipped to the size of the listing:

[image]

### Note:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

### Issues:

This however has some serious issues:

- A blank line is required before the listing (surprising result otherwise).
- Not sure why the fudge facts were required, but they end up aligning the frame to pretty close to where the `fram=tb` option would have drawn the horizontal lines.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\AddBackgroundImage}[4][]{%
%\pgfmathsetmacrp{\height}{}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \coordinate (VCenter) at ($(#2)!0.5!(#3)$);
    \coordinate (Fudge) at (-\pgflinewidth,0);
    \coordinate (VFudge) at (0,\baselineskip);
    %\draw [red, thick,fill=yellow, fill opacity=0.2]% for debugging
    \clip
            ($(#2)+ (Fudge) - 0.50*(VFudge)$) -- 
            ($(#2) + (\linewidth,0) - 0.50*(VFudge)$) -- 
            ($(#3) + (\linewidth,0) + 1.25*(VFudge)$) --
            ($(#3)+ (Fudge) + 1.25*(VFudge)$) -- cycle;
    \path (VCenter) -- ++($(0.5*\linewidth,0)$) 
    node [opacity=0.3, #1] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#4}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%


\lstset{
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    %frame=tb,
    numbers=left,
    xleftmargin=5.0ex,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    numbersep=4pt,
    stepnumber=2,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries
    }

\lstset{emph={%  Adjust any special keywords
    printf%
    },emphstyle={\color{red}\bfseries}%
}%


\begin{document}
\noindent
Here is an example of listings with a background image:

\noindent% Line above MUST be blank
\tikzmark{Start}%
\begin{lstlisting}
/* Hello World program */

#include<stdio.h>

struct cpu_info {
    long unsigned utime, ntime, stime, itime;
    long unsigned iowtime, irqtime, sirqtime;
};

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}\end{lstlisting}
\tikzmark{End}
\AddBackgroundImage{Start}{End}{images/EiffelWide}%
%
\noindent
Some text afterwards.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very beautiful background... But the original question is "It there a way to do this" and not "How to do this". ;-)

Comment: @PolGab -- Come on. Give a guy a break! :-)

Comment: Tried using this technique with the beamer package. Did not work. I just get a grey box around the listing.

Comment: If the codes are long enough to span multiple pages, then what happen? :-)

Comment: @HiggsBoson: Yep, this solution won't work in that case.