# PNG as a background?

Tags: transparency, png, watermark

Is it possible to use a PNG image as a background, but with selected opacity? It seems to me that standard solutions found here can not change opacity of PNG...

I assume, that in the following one of the flags should be near transparent (taken from [Includegraphics: set image opacity](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86500/includegraphics-set-image-opacity)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\transparent{0.01}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{it.png}
\medskip

\transparent{0.99}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{it.png}

\end{document}
```

but the result is:

[image]

where it.png is

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Here is an example of using a background image with opacity: [Background images for code listings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63580/background-images-for-code-listings).  We'd really have to see a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to figure out why what you tried did not work for you.

Comment: @PeterGrill It is rather MNWE (minimal non working example).

Comment: That depends on whether Peter means the *document* is working, or that the *error* is working...`:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have to run pdflatex twice for the transparency to kick in for your original tex source. The package actually prints out a message to say that when you run it the first time.

Comment: Congratulations! Very good start on tex.se!

Answer (score 8):

As a fan of both `tikz` and `background`, here's a version showing four different opacities:

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=5mm,a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[angle=0,scale=20,opacity=1,color=black]{background}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{%
    contents={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myopacity}{mod(\thepage-1,4)*0.25+0.25}
            \node[opacity=\myopacity] {\includegraphics[scale=1]{avatar.png}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I have obtained: "! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `angle=0' for package `background'." and so on. :-(

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Which version do you use? I used the `v2.0` natation, which is not compatible with `v1.0`. There you used `\SetBgContents{} \SetBgColor{} \SetBgAngle{} \SetBgOpacity{} \SetBgScale{} \SetBgPosition{} \SetBgAnchor{} \SetBgHshift{} \SetBgVshift{}`. Either change to the old syntax or upgrade to `v2.0` (if that is the problem).