# A line of text with proper positioning but consuming no space?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

<sub>Welcome to part 4 in a series of questions about me trying to improve my crazy layout!</sub>

I'm using `tabu` to create a table with a central heading, and two small blocks of text on the left and right which are vertically centered.

Now I'd like to add a small subheading — but **the main heading should still be vertically centered with respect to the left and right text blocks**. Here's the starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu} 

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabu}{|X[m,c]|X[-2,m,c]|X[m,c]|} \tabucline \\
    \scriptsize This is something \linebreak on the left
    &
    \Huge Here's a Title
    &
    \scriptsize And here's some stuff \linebreak on the \linebreak right side
    \\ \tabucline \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

When I use

```
\Huge Here's a Title \linebreak \normalsize And a subtitle!
```

I get this:

[image]

Clearly the centering is preserved overall, but I don't want the subtitle to contribute to the positioning. So I tried `\smash`:

```
\Huge Here's a Title \smash{\linebreak \normalsize And a subtitle!}
```

But the result is no better (in fact, it's worse):

[image]

(And I tried some other arrangements too, to no avail.) Is there any way to do this, or am I crazy for trying?

Comment: I am not sure where the sub title is supposed to go? On top of the last `\tabucline`? Do you want it below that perhaps?

Comment: @PeterGrill It should be below the main title, except I don't want it to take up any space (so maybe it will overlap with the `\tabucline`, I don't care about that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments you seem to want to make sure that the subtitle does not take up any space. Well, my usual *overkill* option of using `tikz` provides a method to place text without influencing the positioning.

You mark the two end points of where you want the text centered via a `\tikzmark` and give each of these marks a name. Then after the table you can place text anywhere relative to these marked points.  Below I have set the default (show in red) placement below the title, but you can also use the first optional parameter to the `\AddSubTitle` macro to tweak the positioning and color as I have done in the second example (text in blue):

[image]

I am not sure that you would want to place text on top of the `\tabucline`, but that might make sense for an ornament.  Anyway you have the flexibility to place it where you want.

Perhaps something like this first example below might be useful where I have added a white fill around the text so that the subtitle is not obscured:

[image]

### Notes:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand*{\AddSubTitle}[4][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = left point
    % #3 = right point
    % #4 = text
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \coordinate (MidPoint) at ($(#2.south)!0.5!(#3.south)$);
        \node [red, #1] at (MidPoint)  {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\newcommand{\MyTabu}{%  Make it easier to repeat for testing purposes
\noindent
\begin{tabu}{|X[m,c]|X[-2,m,c]|X[m,c]|} \tabucline \\
    \scriptsize This is something \linebreak on the left
    &
    \Huge \tikzmark{left}Here's a Title\tikzmark{right}
    &
    \scriptsize And here's some stuff \linebreak on the \linebreak right side
    \\ \tabucline \\
\end{tabu}
}%
\begin{document}

\MyTabu
\AddSubTitle{left}{right}{And a subtitle!}

\vspace*{1.0cm}
\MyTabu
\AddSubTitle[blue, yshift=0.2cm]{left}{right}{And a subtitle!}

\vspace*{1.0cm}
\MyTabu
\AddSubTitle[red, yshift=0.5cm, rotate=45]{left}{right}{And a subtitle!}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can locally disable the interline skip mechanism:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabu}{|X[m,c]|X[-2,m,c]|X[m,c]|} \tabucline
    \scriptsize This is something \linebreak on the left
    &
    \offinterlineskip
    \Huge\strut Here's a Title\par
    \vspace{-2pt}
    \normalsize\strut And a subtitle
    &
    \scriptsize And here's some stuff \linebreak on the \linebreak right side
    \\\tabucline\\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

The `\vspace{-2pt}` seems necessary, particularly because the huge title has no descenders. By inserting struts you ensure that the characters don't touch the lines.

[image]

Alternatively, put the subtitle in another row:

```
\noindent
\begin{tabu}{|X[m,c]|X[-2,m,c]|X[m,c]|} \tabucline
    \scriptsize This is something \linebreak on the left
    &
    \Huge\strut Here's a Title
    &
    \scriptsize And here's some stuff \linebreak on the \linebreak right side
    \\
    & And a subtitle & \\
\tabucline\\
\end{tabu}
```

[image]

Comment: Even with `\offinterlineskip` the title is in different positions with/without the subtitle; I want it to stay in the same place. Putting it in a new row would work except then its proximity to the main title is constrained by the left and right cell heights.

Answer (score 2):

Put the subtitle in a centred multicolumn spanning the three columns (I put a `\strut` after the huge title to have better spacing):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu} 

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabu}{|X[m,c]|X[-2,m,c]|X[m,c]|} \tabucline \\
    \scriptsize This is something \linebreak on the left
    &
    \Huge Here's a Title\strut
    &
    \scriptsize And here's some stuff \linebreak on the \linebreak right side
    \\\tabucline\\
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Her is the subtitle}\\ \tabucline \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or just in a separate row (experiment with `\strut` after the subtitle to see if you find the spacing better):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu} 

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabu}{|X[m,c]|X[-2,m,c]|X[m,c]|} \tabucline \\
    \scriptsize This is something \linebreak on the left
    &
    \Huge Here's a Title\strut
    &
    \scriptsize And here's some stuff \linebreak on the \linebreak right side
    \\
& Her is the subtitle \strut &\\ \tabucline \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your third option is to use the package [textpos](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/textpos). By placing :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textpos} 
\usepackage{tabu}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{\textwidth}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\textheight}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabu}{|X[m,c]|X[-2,m,c]|X[m,c]|} \tabucline \\
    \scriptsize This is something \linebreak on the left
    &
    \Huge Here's a Title\strut
    &
    \scriptsize And here's some stuff \linebreak on the \linebreak right side
 \\ \tabucline \\
\end{tabu}

\begin{textblock}{0.8}[0.5,0.5](0.5,-0.01)
\noindent\centering Subtitle
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need all the extra space in the last image?

Comment: No, but `standalone` is not compatible with `textpos`, and I had no time for cropping.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be happy with `phantom` space?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabu}{|X[m,c]|X[-2,m,c]|X[m,c]|} \tabucline \\
    \scriptsize This is something \linebreak on the left
    &
     \phantom{And a subtitle!} \Huge Here's a Title \linebreak \normalsize And a subtitle!
    &
    \scriptsize And here's some stuff \linebreak on the \linebreak right side
    \\ \tabucline \\
\end{tabu}

\noindent OR

\noindent
\begin{tabu}{|X[m,c]|X[-2,m,c]|X[m,c]|} \tabucline \\
    \scriptsize This is something \linebreak on the left \linebreak  \phantom{And a subtitle!}
    &
     \Huge Here's a Title \linebreak \normalsize And a subtitle!
    &
    \scriptsize And here's some stuff \linebreak on the \linebreak right side
    \linebreak \phantom{And a subtitle!}
    \\ \tabucline \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]