# mtpro2 and tikzmark conflict

Tags: tikz-pgf, incompatibility, mtpro, tikzmark

The `\tikzmark` command (as in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570)) does not work within the `\PARENS` command provided by the `mtpro2` package.

Here is a MWE (requiring at least two runs):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}
$$\PARENS{\tikzmark{a}1}$$ %With PARENS

$$\tikzmark{b}(1)$$ %Without PARENS

\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {
\draw (a) circle (1cm); %With PARENS - ends up at the bottom left corner of page
\draw (b) circle (1cm); %Without PARENS - works fine
}
\end{document}
```

Would appreciate any explanations and/or remedies. Thanks

Comment: (I'm not able to test this right now, hence just a comment.) Try the pgfmark variant from the experimental tikzmark package. Search for TeX-SX Launchpad here for the link.

Comment: What about `$$\tikzmark{a}\PARENS{1}$$` ?

Comment: @JLDiaz In this example yes, but most of the time large matrices sit within `\PARENS`, and `\tikzmark` is used to mark different positions within these matrices

Comment: Ah, I understand. What about `$$\PARENS{{\tikzmark{a}}1}$$`?

Comment: @JLDiaz Doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot test, because I do not have package `mtpro2` installed. From source code analysis I would say, that `\tikzmark` is set twice in box `\LRbox@` and a box inside macro `\EXtest@`. Since the former is used to typeset the result, `\tikzmark` is disabled in `\EXtest@` to avoid duplicate `\tikzmark`'s:

```
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\LEFTRIGHT@}[3]{%
  \setbox\LRbox@\vc@nt@r{#3}%  
  \EXtest@{%
    \renewcommand*{\tikzmark}[1]{}%
    \vc@nt@r{#3}%
  }%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\curlybraces\EXtest@@$\displaystyle\left#1\box\LRbox@\right#2$}}%
}%
\makeatother
```

Comment: The same I was thinking. It would be better if `\LEFTRIGHT@` used a conditional, similarly to `amsmath`'s `\ifmeasuring@`.