# Curvy arrows between two tables (with tikz?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I try to connect two arbitrary tables with arrows. The code example below should demonstrate how: say we want to connect the "1" in A with the "5" in B, the "2" in A with the "7" in B and so on. My wish would be to have "curvy" arrows (as far as i know the `tikz` packages provides them) and not "straight" arrows.

Is it even possible to combine "ordinary" tabular elements with `tikz` nodes oder drawings? 
If yes, how? If not, is there a pure `tikz` way to solve that problem? Thanks for any advices or hints!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}
\begin{document} 
\begin{center}

  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
   $A$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{15mm}

  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c }
   $B$ & \fbox{5} & 6 & \fbox{7} & 8 & \fbox{9} & 10 & \fbox{11} & 12 &  
  \end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

[image]

### Note:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\DrawArrow}[3][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = left point
    % #3 = right point
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw [very thick, -stealth, #1] ($(#2)+(0.25em,-0.3ex)$) to ($(#3)+(0.25em,2.5ex)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document} 
\begin{center}

  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
   $A$ & \tikzmark{topA}1 & \tikzmark{topB}2 & \tikzmark{topC}3 & \tikzmark{topD}4 & 
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{15mm}

  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c }
   $B$ & \fbox{\tikzmark{bottomA}5} & 6 & \fbox{\tikzmark{bottomB}7} & 8 & \fbox{\tikzmark{bottomC}9} & 10 & \fbox{\tikzmark{bottomD}11} & 12 &  
  \end{tabular}
\DrawArrow[red,   out=-90, in=90]{topA}{bottomA}
\DrawArrow[olive, out=-90, in=90]{topB}{bottomB}
\DrawArrow[blue,  out=-90, in=90]{topC}{bottomC}
\DrawArrow[brown, out=-90, in=90]{topD}{bottomD}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! That's exactly my desired representation. Thank you very much for the quick response and the understandable code style!

Comment: Wait... I wasn't done... Solution now updated with a better macro interface.

Comment: The vertical line passing through the center of one row is not aligned with that of the other row. In other words, 2 and 8 should be in the same column. :D

Comment: @Karl'sstudents: Not sure I understand. I am just connecting existing text, not adjusting it. The positions can be adjusted as needed.

Comment: I meant, 2 and 8 should be in the same column. In other words, 8 should be right below 2 such that 3 and 9 are connected with a straight line. By the way, it is not crucial issue. :-)

Comment: @Karl'sstudents: OK, but am going to leave that alone as that is not the thrust of this question.

Comment: i've chosen an "easy as possible" mapping - my mapping here is more complicated but that doesn't matter, it's all about the programming procedure. Thank you two for your effort!

Answer (score 4):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset
{
    mnode=r,
    rowsep=2cm,
    colsep=0.5cm,
}

\def\c{[mnode=circle] }


\begin{document}
\offinterlineskip
\begin{psmatrix}
    & & A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    B & \c 5 & 6 & \c 7 & 8 & \c 9 & 10 & \c 11 & 12
    \foreach \i/\j in {4/2,5/4,6/6,7/8}
        {\nccurve[angleA=-90,angleB=90,nodesep=3pt]{->}{1,\i}{2,\j}}
\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

### Warning:

- `mnode` for `\psframebox` is not available out of the box. We can circumvent it by wrapping each item with `\psframebox` manually, but it will take more keystrokes!
- `mnode=circle` will use `\pscirclebox` to wrap the item. Unfortunately, `\pscirclebox` has no option to adjust its radius. It results in the size of each circle will vary depending on the size of the contained item. Only `framesep` is available to adjust the border. Sad!

Comment: @Karls students: looks very stylish too! Thanks for the pratical alternative!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very short solution using the `tikz-cd` package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[out=-90, in=90, column sep=small, row sep=15mm]
    & & A & 1 \arrow{dll} & 2 \arrow{dl} & 3 \arrow{d} & 4 \arrow{dr} \\
    B & \fbox{5} & 6 & \fbox{7} & 8 & \fbox{9} & 10 & \fbox{11} & 12
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The result is this:

[image]

Note that the table entries created by this method will automatically be in math mode. Any entries for which this behavior is undesired should have their text enclosed in a `\text{}` command.

Comment: @ Charles Staats: very clear and simple approach - nice!