# How can I draw paths in Karnaugh maps?

Tags: karnaugh

I would like to draw something like this:

[image]

So I would like to highlight the path from 13 -> 9 -> 11 -> 3. **How can I draw this path in a Karnough map?**

edit: It don't has to be done with `kvmacros`, but I would like to have an example with which I can create other Karnaugh maps (with other marks of blocks of ones) without problems.

The Karnaugh map was pretty streight forward, although I would rather like the x at the bottom and w at the right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\input{kvmacros}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
    \karnaughmap{4}{$f(w,x,y,z)$}{{$w$}{$x$}{$y$}{$z$}}%
    {
        1100
        1100
        0011
        0101
    }
    {
        \textcolor{Blue}{
            \put(2,3.5){\oval(3.9,0.9)[]}
        }
        \textcolor{WildStrawberry}{
            \put(0.9,3.5){\oval(1.7,0.8)[]}
        }
        \textcolor{Green}{
            \put(0.7,1.5){\oval(1.9,0.9)}
        }
        \textcolor{Sepia}{
            \put(1.5,1.5){\oval(1.6,0.7)}
        }
        \textcolor{Red}{
            \put(1.92,1){\oval(0.9,1.9)}
        }
        \textcolor{LimeGreen}{
            \put(1.76,-0.2){\oval(0.9,2.1)[t]}
            \put(1.76,4.2){\oval(0.9,2.1)[b]}
        }
    }
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the best way would be to use `\tikzmark`, but now sure where you are getting the magic coordinates from?

Comment: Out of topic: you can reduce the number of keystrokes by using `\documentclass[preview,border=2mm]{standalone}` and removing `\begin{preview}` and `\end{preview}` from your document body. Thanks!

Comment: @Karl'sstudents: `standalone` does quite often not crop the image the the correct part, so I take `preview` in most of my [examples](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/tikz).

Comment: @moose: With the option `preview` to the `standalone` class, you will do the same thing as you load `preview` package. One more benefit, you no longer need to explicitly specify `\begin{preview}...\end{preview}`. By the way, your GitHub is very interesting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of using `tikzmark`:

[image]

### Note:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).
- Also, I don't know how those coordinates were determined so I just piggy backed onto the existing nodes so added the `tikzmark` to `13` and `11` and used `shorten >= -4.5ex` to stretch into the node above it.
- The drawing quality of the `picture` mode `\oval` does not seem very good, but perhaps there is someone on this site who can address that issue.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\input{kvmacros}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay, remember picture, baseline] \node (#1) {};%
}

\newcommand{\DrawArrow}[3][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[
                ->, thick,% distance=\ArcDistance,
                %shorten <=\ShortenBegin, shorten >=\ShortenEnd,
                %out=\OutAngle, in=\InAngle, Arrow Style, #2
                #1
            ] 
                ($(#2)+(-0.50em,3.5ex)$) to 
                ($(#3)+(1.5em,0.0ex)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}% <-- important
}

\begin{document}
    \karnaughmap{4}{$f(w,x,y,z)$}{{$w$}{$x$}{$y$}{$z$}}%
    {
        1100
        1100
        0011
        0101
    }
    {
        \textcolor{Blue}{
            \put(2,3.5){\oval(3.9,0.9)[]}
        }
        \textcolor{WildStrawberry}{
            \put(0.9,3.5){\oval(1.7,0.8)[]}
        }
        \textcolor{Green}{
            \put(0.7,1.5){\tikzmark{11}\oval(1.9,0.9)}
        }
        \textcolor{Sepia}{
            \put(1.5,1.5){\oval(1.6,0.7)}
        }
        \textcolor{Red}{
            \put(1.92,1){\oval(0.9,1.9)}
        }
        \textcolor{LimeGreen}{
            \put(1.76,-0.2){\tikzmark{13}\oval(0.9,2.1)[t]}
            \put(1.76,4.2){\oval(0.9,2.1)[b]}
        }
    }
\DrawArrow[red, ultra thick, out=-180, in=-90, distance=1.5em, shorten >= -4.5ex]{13}{11}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I think I know how to get better results. You can use `convert`. See [my Makefile](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/tikz/karnaugh-map). This Makefile produces [this image](http://martin-thoma.com/kv-diagramme/#Beispiel). I take deeper a look (and quite likely accept) at your answer tomorrow. Have to sleep now.

Comment: Ok, but the quality of the drawing capability of `kvmacros` seems very poor. You should consider doing the entire drawing in `tikz`.