# How to draw flow lines on tabular?

Tags: tables, karnaugh

I have created a tabular in latex and I would like to have flow lines on it, pointing from one element to an other. I do not care how it looks like, I just want to show there is a flow from one element to an other and so on. I would also like to do the same for Karnaugh maps. No matter how much I've searched the web, there hasn't even been someone to ask this sort of question.  Does anyone have any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Related: [How can I draw paths in Karnaugh maps?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104285/3345) and [other Karnaugh-related questions and answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=karnaugh). An example image of the effect you're looking for, or a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have already would help people figure out how best to help.

Comment: You also can do that with the `pst-node` package, from the `pstricks` family.

Comment: For the tabular case: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163174/table-with-arrows-between-cells?rq=1

Comment: Well, I didn't have an exact effect in my mind, any would do, so I avoided posting an image, because I felt it would limit the type of answers. What you have posted is more than enough.