# Graphical vertical rule in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, documentclass-writing

I would like to make design (class), where I would like to have special type of paragraph that will have `{` character on left and will have height exactly same as height of whole paragraph. Also, I would like to extend it that any tikz picture could be scaled based on length (height) of paragraph.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: this sounds a lot like [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1559) which is where `tikzmark` made its first appearance- please let us know if your question is different, and if so, how :)

Comment: Yep, that `tikzmark` looks as possible way to go, but in that question they are applying it to list and I need it in paragraph. `pstricks-add.sty` solution does exactly what I need except I need it with `tikz` because my actual image more complicated design. thanks, a lot for that link

Comment: What exactly are you planning to use instead of the brace? Notice that decorations have some restrictions, depending on what can be used to decorate.

Comment: The `scalerel` package can produce a symbol of your choice to the exact size of a target object.  In this case, though, I think the paragraph material would have to be stuffed into a box (e.g., a `\parbox`), before scalerel could match it.  Whether that approach would work for you, I'm not sure.  Might depend on whether you invoke this special kind of paragraph as a command (yes it would work) or as an environment (maybe it could work).

Comment: I want to have several types of paragraphs, special command for each. This brace, and [this type of circle paragraphs] (http://i.imgur.com/7lc3GUl.png) and many others. That is why I am asking for general tikz solution. Now I have something like this `\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};
    \draw[-] (char) -- +(0,-1);
  }` , but that is scaled only 1 unit, I need some variable of paragraph height. Ideally I would like to have ability to scale it also through page breaks.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I commented on above, if usage is in command, rather than environment, form.

Note that scalerel does a perfect scale of the "{" symbol, until the width reaches the value of the optional argument (in this case 1in).  For scales larger then that, the width is constrained to 1in, effectively making it a stretch, rather than a scale, beyond that point.  This will prevent the symbol from growing too wide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\specpar[1]{%
\begin{flushright}
  \scalerel[1in]{\{}{\parbox{4in}{#1}}%
\end{flushright}
}
\parindent 0in
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\specpar{\lipsum[2]}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With PSTricks. Compile it with `xelatex` for the sake of simplicity.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{bera}
\begin{document}
Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns. 
Karl's students do not care about arrow tips. 
Karl's students, by the way, do not know what a transformation matrix is.

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
\noindent\rnode{A}{\strut}

\vspace*{-1ex}
Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns. 
Karl's students do not care about arrow tips. 
Karl's students, by the way, do not know what a transformation matrix is.

\vspace*{-2ex}
\noindent\rnode{B}{}
\psbrace[braceWidthInner=3pt,braceWidth=1pt,braceWidthOuter=5pt,linecolor=red](A)(B){}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns. 
Karl's students do not care about arrow tips. 
Karl's students, by the way, do not know what a transformation matrix is.
\end{document}
```