# Combining Tables and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

There are a few accounting figures which I am making, and I need to add curly braces and arrows with boxes of text inside near table environments. Here is an example figure:
[image: example]

I want to use TikZ for this, in combination with a tabular enviroment maybe? This just looks so difficult that I'm not even sure what to start with to give you a sample code of my attempt. Also, I'm not sure how to use a 'rule' style command which just underlines a certain column as in the figure, not the entire row.

Comment: I think you want `\cmidrule{a-b}` which will draw a midrule between column a and column b. `\midrule` draws one the whole width of the table. Or, without `booktabs` (not recommended), use `\cline{a-b}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=6.5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3.25em]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\def \n {3}
\coordinate (a0) at (\n,-0.5);
\coordinate (a1) at (\n,-1);
\coordinate (a2) at (\n,-1.5);
\draw[decoration={brace,amplitude=0.6em,mirror},decorate,ultra thick,gray]($(a1)!(a0.north)!($(a1)-(0,1)$)$) --  ($(a1)!(a2.south)!($(a1)-(0,1)$)$);
\node[block] at ($(a1)-(1.85,0)$) {text 1};

\coordinate (b1) at (\n,-2.5);
\draw[->,ultra thick,gray](b1) --  ($(b1)+(1,0)$);
\node[block] at ($(b1)-(1.85,0)$) {text 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
Bla, bla\ldots\\[2mm]

\begin{tabular}{lll}
A & B & C\\
1 & 3 & 3\\
2 & 4 & 6
\end{tabular}

text \ldots
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The rest is fine tuning of the coordinates.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to figure out how all of this works from your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I personally would recommend using the infamous `\tikzmark`.  With this you:

- complete the table as you normally would
- mark specfic points with a `\tikzmark{<name>}`
- access these `\tikzmark`s in a `\tikzpicture` with the `[overlay,remember picture]` options and draw as desired.

This allows one to separate the tabular date form the drawings that needs to be added.

[image]

### Note:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[baseline] (#1) {};}

\tikzset{My Node Style/.style={midway, right, xshift=3.0ex, align=left, font=\small, draw=blue, thin, fill=cyan!25, text=black}}

\newcommand\VerticalBrace[4][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = top mark
    % #2 = bottom mark
    % #4 = label
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace, amplitude=1.5ex}, #1] 
    ([yshift=1ex]#2.north east)  -- ([yshift=-1ex]#3.south east)
        node[My Node Style] {#4};
}

\newcommand\DrawArrow[3][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = mark
    % #3 = label
  \draw[<-, shorten >=0.1cm, #1] 
    ([shift={(0.0cm,0.5ex)}]#2.east)  -- ([shift={(1.0cm,0.5ex)}]#2.east)
        node[My Node Style] {#3};
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llrr}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Big Dog Carworks Corp.}\tikzmark{Heading Top} \\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Income Statement} \\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{For the month eded Jan. 31, 2015}\tikzmark{Heading Bottom} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Revenues} \\[0.5ex]
    & Repair Revenues && \$ \num{15000} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Expenses} \\
    & Rent Expense & \$ \num{1500} \\
    & Salaries Expense & \$ \num{3500} \\
    & Supplies Expense & \$ \num{3500} \\
    & Fuel Expense & \$ \num{3500} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    & Total Expenses && \$ \num{12000} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
    & Net Income     && \$ \num{03000} \tikzmark{Net Income Mark}\\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \VerticalBrace[ultra thick, blue]{Heading Top}{Heading Bottom}{%
        The heading shows the name \\
        of the entity, the type of \\
        financial statement, and the \\
        \textit{period-in-time} date.%
    }
    \DrawArrow[ultra thick, blue]{Net Income Mark}{%
        The net income is transferred \\
        to the statement of changes \\
        in equity.%
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```