# list/tree with arrows from main word

Tags: lists, arrows, trees

Can anybody help me to do something like this in LaTeX?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  If you can't do the arrows you should at least be able to set up the text in the proper position.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: this is a screenshot from MS Word which was sent to me. I can set up text to proper position in LaTex, but I absolutely don't know how to do the arrows

Comment: Just set up dummy text in the right positions, then I am sure you'll get answers on how to draw the arrows. Basically, try to make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try with a `tree`. Next example is done with `forest` package

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} for tree={grow'=0,l=2cm, anchor=west, child anchor=west, edge=->}, for descendants={node options={text width=8cm,align=left}}
[root 
    [{\begin{description}\item[First] This is the first item of my list .  This is the first item of my list.  This is the first item of my list.  This is the first item of my list\end{description}}]
    [{\begin{description}\item[Second] This is the second item of my list .  This is the second item of my list.  This is the second item of my list.  This is the second item of my list\end{description}}]
    [third]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an illustration of how to use `\tikz` and `\tikzmark` to add arrows between specific points int he document. You mark the positions with `\tikzmark` and then invoke the `\DrawArrow` macro to connect each of the points.

[image]

### Notes:

- This is intended only to show you how to draw the arrows as I did not pay much attention to the text placement (which does not seem to be the thrust of the question).
- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand*{\DrawArrow}[3][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = left point
    % #3 = right point
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw [very thick, -stealth, #1] ($(#2.east)+(0em,0.7ex)$) to ($(#3.west)+(0.0em,0.7ex)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\hspace*{3.0cm}\tikzmark{End 1}B

A\tikzmark{Start} 

\hspace*{3.0cm}\tikzmark{End 2}C
\DrawArrow{Start}{End 1}
\DrawArrow[red]{Start}{End 2}
\end{document}
```