# Adding a large brace next to itemize: beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, itemize, braces

How can I add a large "}" (that covers top to bottom of Part 2) to the right of all texts of Part 2 on layer number 7? I don't "}" to be at right end of the frame because I want to write "Part 2" at the right hand side of it. Any idea?

```
\begin{frame}
%%%% Part1%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> A
\end{itemize}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%% Part2%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
\item<2-> B
\item<3-> C: 
\begin{itemize}
\item<4-> C1,
\item<5-> C2.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%% Part3%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
\item<6-> D
\end{itemize}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Does this answer help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1570/103046?

Comment: @Tiuri No, it is not what I want. That solution seems very old. Every time I generate my pdf, it puts } at a different location!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
%%%% Part1%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> A
\end{itemize}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%% Part2%%%%%

\begin{itemize}
\item<2-> B\tikzmark{start}
\item<3-> C: 
\begin{itemize}
\item<4-> C1,
\item<5-> C2.\tikzmark{end}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%% Part3%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
\item<6-> Limited to finite horizon problems
\end{itemize}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace}]
        ([yshift=10pt,xshift=60pt]{{pic cs:end}|-{pic cs:start}}) --
        node[xshift=5pt,anchor=west] {Part 2}
        ([xshift=60pt]{pic cs:end})
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*(Thanks to @Loop Space for suggesting the `calligraphic brace`!)*

Comment: hm, but `{`  is on the left side :-), not on right, a s i understood the question ..

Comment: Beat me to it ... mine had a `calligraphic brace`, but I guess that's not enough for a separate answer.

Comment: @LoopSpace Please feel free to add a clean answer. Mine is mostly a hack with many manual spaces - I'll happily delete it!

Comment: The only difference was that rather than trying to do everything in one `\draw` command then I defined a few coordinates first.  My `tikzpicture` code was: `\coordinate (c) at ([xshift=1cm]pic cs:b);
\node[anchor=base] (a) at (pic cs:a) {};
\draw<7>[decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace}] (a -| c) -- ({pic cs:b} -| c);
`

Comment: One of the problems of these questions is that spaces depend on the *actual* contents, not the MWE contents, so I don't recommend over-thinking the spacing.  Leave it hacky unless further information is given.

Comment: @LoopSpace Thanks for suggesting the calligraphic brace! It really looks better!

Comment: I'm just trying to see how many of my packages I can get you to include in one answer.

Comment: @LoopSpace :) I could replace replace the itemize items with celtic knots - I bet this would nice!

Comment: I *like* that idea!