# \hfill doesn't work for braces in mathmode

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, brackets

I want a right brace that spans a few lines of text and is located at the right-most side of page.\

Something like this :

[image: Right brace around text]

Related : [brackets - Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1563/209459)

Here, the following code doesn't seem to work :

```
$\left.\begin{tabular}{l}
line \\
one more line
\end{tabular}\hfill\right\}$
```

Are there alternatives for `\hfill` that will work ?

Comment: Please start by explaining what hvis piece of gode is suppose to do in the first place. Hfill doesnt make much sense here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd abuse `equation*` for a couple of reasons:

1. automatic vertical spacing around the construction;
2. avoiding page breaks before the construction.

The contents of the `braceonright` environment is typeset as a `tabular` and reused for getting the right size of the brace. This is neessary, because `\hfill` does nothing if inside a `\left`-`\right` pair.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newsavebox{\braceonrightbox}
\newenvironment{braceonright}
 {%
  \begin{equation*}% abuse equation* for spacing and other features
  \hspace{0pt}% necessary
  \begin{lrbox}{\braceonrightbox}% save the contents
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}%
 }
 {%
  \end{tabular}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \usebox{\braceonrightbox}
  \hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}
  \left.\vphantom{\usebox{\braceonrightbox}}\right\rbrace
  \end{equation*}\ignorespacesafterend
 }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-6]
\begin{braceonright}
line \\
one more line
\end{braceonright}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The trick is to add a very large space (1000pt) that can be shrinked to the actual width; in order for this to work, there must be some glue (0pt) at the beginning of the “equation”.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! This works exactly how I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 3):

Hm, something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\par\noindent
$\left.\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}
line \\
one more line
\end{tabular}\right\}$
\par
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

[image]