# How can I insert a large curly bracket across multiple lines of text?

Tags: symbols, brackets

I am attempting to group multiple lines of text with a curly bracket that will have text centered on the right side of the bracket:

[image]

My current MWE does not include the bracket.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent a\\
b $\quad\longrightarrow$ d\\
c\\

\end{document}
```

How can I insert the bracket whilst ensuring that I can enter vertically centered text on the right of the bracket?

Comment: This would be much more common in math than in text.  Are you certain this is truly text and not math?  Regardless, the best approach might be to typeset it as if it were math, but just use `\text{...}` everywhere.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent $\left.\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{tabular}\right\}
\quad\longrightarrow$ d

\end{document}`?

Comment: i do believe comment section is not meant for inputting answers code

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking in a comment if some suggestion goes in the right direction. Answers should be reserved for sufficiently original codes that answer the question.

Comment: @Teepeemm there would be a combination of math and text, but as it won't be too long I won't object using `\text` within a math environment.

Comment: @abcdefg works perfectly, thank you. Post as an answer if you wish.

Comment: Do the answers at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1559/86 help you?

Comment: @AndrewStacey yes they do, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try with:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{rcases}
\mathrm{a}\\
\mathrm{b}\\
\mathrm{c}
\end{rcases}\longrightarrow \mathrm{d}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\mathrm` shouldn't be used for text; it should be `\text`.  Although an actual example from the OP would have been nice.

Comment: And `\textnormal` unless you want the text italicized within an italicized theorem statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a MWE also using a simple array (with the vertical spaces between the equations `[.5ex]`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\left.\begin{array}{r} 
\textnormal{a}\\[.5ex]
\textnormal{b}\\[.5ex]
\textnormal{c}
\end{array} \right\} 
\longrightarrow \textnormal{d}
\]
\end{document}
```

Here there is the output:

[image]

Comment: Note that, if you use this figure within a theorem statement where the text is italicized, `\text` will be italicized too. Maybe that’s what you want. To get the effect of `\mathrm`, which always gives you regular-weight, upright text, use `\textnormal`.

Comment: @Davislor Very kind, thank you very much for your advice. In this period I am very busy with the school, discouraged and I am connecting very little. Thanks again and I will make the change.