# Typesetting verse; want to eliminate all padding to left of tabular environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting

I am setting a poem by William Cowper as published in an early 19th-century edition of his work. It uses a curly brace from time to time to mark a rhyming triplet (instead of the usual rhyming couplets). I'm trying to recreate this effect.

Based on a few similar questions on this site and my own reading on the `tabular` environment, the solution I've come up with so far is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{verse}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
  
  He breaks the cord that held him at the rack\,;\\
  And, conscious of an unincumber'd back,\\
  Snuffs up the morning air, forgets the rein,\\
  Loose fly his forelock and his ample mane\,;\\
  $\left.
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Responsive to the distant neigh he neighs\,;\\
    Nor stops, till, overleaping all delays,\\
    He finds the pasture where his fellows graze.
  \end{tabular}
  \right\}$\\
  \vin Canst thou, and honour'd with a Christian name,\\
  Buy what is woman born, and feel no shame\,?\\
  
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: MWE output of Cowper's "Charity"]

It's *almost* perfect, but there's a tiny-but-noticeable amount of padding on the left margin of the bracketed lines.

Can anyone suggest an adjustment to my markup that would eliminate even that?

Comment: The space probably domes from the transition to math mode, not the tabular itself.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119869/11604

Comment: Thank you, Fran. The accepted answer to that question doesn't appear too different from my own (and I believe I may have read that question while trying to solve this). Though I was hoping to avoid multiplying packages needlessly, the answers using the `tikz` package might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @JohnKormylo \mathsurround is usually 0pt so not visible: this is \nulldelimiterspace from `\left.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}\nulldelimiterspace=0pt

  He breaks the cord that held him at the rack\,;\\
  And, conscious of an unincumber'd back,\\
  Snuffs up the morning air, forgets the rein,\\
  Loose fly his forelock and his ample mane\,;\\
  $\left.
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Responsive to the distant neigh he neighs\,;\\
    Nor stops, till, overleaping all delays,\\
    He finds the pasture where his fellows graze.
  \end{tabular}
  \right\}$\\
  \vin Canst thou, and honour'd with a Christian name,\\
  Buy what is woman born, and feel no shame\,?\\
  
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just that, eh? It works perfectly. Thanks! (And also to everyone who helped.)